# how to get the selected row using T-Sql in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, max

i have a following format of the result set in sql server

```
TagId   Tag   Views
1       A     1234
1       A     123
```

i want to get the record with the highest views and ignore the rest, i mean resultset should have only first row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    select Tagid, Tag, Views, Rank() over (Partition BY TagId, Tag order by Views DESC) as Rank
    from table1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select top 1 *
from tableName
order by Views desc
```

or

```
select max(columnName)
from TableName
```

first one will return whole row (all columns), latter will return scalar value

Answer (score 1):

```
Select A.myGROUP, A.Amt
from mtest A
  INNER JOIN (Select myGroup, max(Amt) as minAmt from mtest group by mygroup) B
  ON B.myGroup=A.mygroup
  and B.MinAmt = A.Amt
```

if you need to get additional data: or if you don't

```
Select tagId, tag, max(views)
FROM table
group by tagId, tag
```

Answer (score 0):

When there's more than one row that share the maximum `Views` value and you want all of them, you could also use [`TOP (n) WITH TIES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
 SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
 FROM atable
 ORDER BY Views DESC
```